# If my domains expire and my hosting is still active, how can I get my previous site to display on a new domain?

Tags: domains

Ok, so here's what happened. Last year I registered two domains(very important!) with an email address I no longer have access to(and I don't know the security questions). Same with the namecheap account where I registered the domains. So I DO NOT have access to either my email or my registrar account.

So I now can not renew my domains. I hosted them with a different host and they are still active, and here's my question.

I want to know whether or not I can have the same sites that were previously on domain1.com to display and function the same on domain1.info

So in other words, domain1.com is the domain that expired, and I want my new site to be the same but display on domain1.info. Is that possible and if so HOW!?

Thank you so much for any help. I am really ecstatic right now because they won't give me access even though I've proven I purchased the domains!

Answer (score 2):

Contact your hosting company and ask them exactly what you've asked here, and they'll be able to help you out no problem. It's a very minor configuration change to make it happen. They will either be able to do it for you, or give you specific instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have access to change the dns for the .info domain, this would be hard to do. You could have the hosting company change the primary domain name on the account and this would in itself have the root data associate with that domain. But again, you would first need to be sure to have the .info dns resolving to the host.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am not understanding full but if I am then the answer to this should be simple.

By the sounds of it, you no longer have access to the DNS records for domain1.com, but you purchased domain1.info with a registrar that you currently have access to?

If this is the case, it would be as simple as pointing your new domain dns records (domain1.info) to your current host. The site will remain exactly the same, the only thing different is that you will be using a different domain.